# Directly using pure JWPlayer JS (but NOT WP Plugin)

Tags: templates, javascript, jwplayer

First of all, I'm not using WP JWPlayer Plugin. (And i don't want it. And thats the another story)

---

Well in the Template file:

```
wp_register_script('myJW', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/jwplayer.js');
wp_enqueue_script('myJW');
?>

<div id='myJWPlayer'></div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jwplayer("myJWPlayer").setup({
        playlist: "http://www.example.com/playlist.xml",
        listbar: {
                position: 'right',
                size: 250
        },
        width: 700,
        height: 400
    });
});
</script>
```

It is not working, since **even** the `jwplayer("myJWPlayer")` call is **not** being triggered.

---

**Note: This codes are perfectly working in pure HTML sites.**
Any idea please?

Comment: are you using wp_enqueue_script in template file? It should be in your functions.php

Comment: Why don't you use the default built-in audio-player

Comment: @PieterGoosen, default? Do you think default one is capable of all the features that JWPlayer can provide? (like, Playlists and Captions and ABR, etc) I definitely believe not.

Comment: Hi @RajeevVyas, yea but it can also be called from Templates actually, ya? (i've been doing like this for years already) But do you really think it is the reason, pls?

Comment: @シリウス http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: I see your point here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly enqueue your script. You should hook your script to the

```
function enqueue_custom_script() {
     wp_register_script('myJW',  get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/jwplayer.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('myJW');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_script' );
```

Comment: Thats the trick, since the JS is not being called properly. And it needs to be in "functions.php"

Comment: Glad I could be of help. And +1 to adding the function in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

http://www.example.com/playlist.xml  is not valid playlist url. Also you are missing `"` at the end of the url.

Please refer to http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28850/using-the-javascript-api for jwplayer usage.

You also need to call

```
jwplayer().play()
```

Try this,

```
wp_register_script('myJW', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/jwplayer.js',array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script('myJW');
?>

<div id='myJWPlayer'></div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert('am called');
    jwplayer("myJWPlayer").setup({
        playlist: "http://www.example.com/playlist.xml,
        listbar: {
                position: 'right',
                size: 250
        },
        width: 700,
        height: 400
    });
});
</script>
```

Also see browser error log if you receive any error. You can use firebug for firefox, or if you are using chrome just press f12 that will open devlopement console, go to console and reload page. May be you catch some usefull info there.

Also note that it would be wise to register and enqueue script from functions file.

Comment: Yes i have already tried putting `alert()` after the `ready()`. And is called. But as i mentioned, the `jwplayer("myJWPlayer")` is not being triggered.

Comment: @シリウス see my edit.